# Selecy dynamic variable using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the "pbd-ajax-load-posts" WordPress plugin for pagination on load more button. Bottom of the code, code author appends new class each time button the `.btn-more` is clicked. So I need to add a separator after even posts. I append after that class which has even class - my separator line.

So, I need to target that "pbd-alp-placeholder-xx" dynamically, so it does not add the line, where's already added.

```
 $('#content') .append('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
```

This is some lines of code:

```
$('.btn-more').click(function() {

    // Are there more posts to load?
    if(pageNum <= max) {

        // Show that we're working.
        $(this).text('Loading posts...');

        $('.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .post',
            function() {
                // Update page number and nextLink.
                pageNum++;
                nextLink = nextLink.replace(/paged[=].[0-9]?/, 'paged='+ pageNum);

                // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                $('#content')
                    .append('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')


            $(".pbd-alp-placeholder- .even").append('<img src="http://webpage/wp-content/themes/funky/img/two-line-seperator.png" style="width:100%; margin: 25px 0; height: 4px;"/>');
```

I tried something like that, but it didn `t woked out .

```
$(".pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +' .even")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST OPTION**:

Since the developer is appending the code ...

```
$('#content')
  .append('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
```

... could't you simply add something like ...

```
$('#content')
  .append('<div class="pbd-break pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
```

... the `pbd-break` class and this to the CSS code.

```
.pd-break {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

**SECOND OPTION**:

Or, you could simply change the same first line like this ...

```
$('#content')
  .append('<div class="pbd-break pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
  .append("<hr/>")
```

... you could effectively put whatever HTML you wanted where the `<hr/>` is ...

Answer (score 0):

Although the code you posted is not quite clear (blocks not closed and indents a bit confusing), I'd give it a shot:

```
// Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
var placholder = $('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>');
$('#content').append(placeholder);
$(placeholder).append('<img src="http://webpage/wp-content/themes/funky/img/two-line-seperator.png" style="width:100%; margin: 25px 0; height: 4px;"/>');
```

Now again, there is nothing in the code explaining how you get the ".even" class, so I just skipped that part. But if you *can* figure out how to add the class, you'll figure out how to modify the separator logic.